# Does git push -f delete the previous commit history of all branches or one specific one?

Tags: git, github

I have a feature branch and a main one. Having resetted the feature branch to the main one using

```
git reset --hard main
```

I need to push it. If I use git push -f origin featureBranch, will it remove the commit history of all branches or just featureBranch's one?

Comment: `git push -f` does not delete the history of anything.  It causes the branch to point to a different commit, but the old commit (and all its ancestors) are still in the repo.   Nothing is deleted.  (Until possibly at some future point in time the garbage collector may delete any commits that are orphaned.)

Comment: Hence, only your feature branch will be affected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We don't need the history of the featureBranch since it's new, but I don't want to cause issues for the rest of the repository. `git push -f origin featureBranch` will only affect the feature branch, right?